# Unable to find nearby places

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-nearby

I want to find nearby hospitals. My code is working fine but did not show any toast message or nearby locations.
It just shows my current location and does not show my nearby locations. Is this due to google places key?

```
MainActivity.kt

 private String getUrl(double latitude , double longitude , String nearbyPlace){

    StringBuilder googlePlaceUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googlePlaceUrl.append("location="+latitude+","+longitude);
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&radius="+PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&type="+nearbyPlace);
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&key="+"AIzaSyCYjKCCqaFeeCO6zqfuRVudrV5FzrCTkZk");
   // 
googlePlaceUrl.append("&key="+"AIzaSyAHbKWGMnqv0GJhaVj1XKMXFZELdzzXK");

    Log.d("MapsActivity", "url = "+googlePlaceUrl.toString());

    return googlePlaceUrl.toString();
}     

NearbyPlacesData.kt


override fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
    var nearbyPlaceList: List<HashMap<String,String>>
    var parser = DataParser()
    nearbyPlaceList = parser.parse(result)
    showNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlaceList)
    Toast.makeText(context,result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


}

private fun showNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlaceList: List<HashMap<String,String>>){

    for (i in 0 until nearbyPlaceList.size){
        var markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
        var googlePlace = nearbyPlaceList.get(i)

        var placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name")
        var vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity")
        var lat = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"))
        var lng = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"))

        var latLng = LatLng(lat,lng)
        markerOptions.position(latLng)
        markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity)
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))

        mMap!!.addMarker(markerOptions)
        mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
        mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10f))
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I was using PLACES API without activating it. After activation of PLACES API, code is working fine.
Thanks all.